# Getting null properties when launching JBoss EAP 6.4 Management Console

Tags: jboss6.x

Am getting an weird JSON message when I try to access (for the first time) my local JBoss EAP 6.4's management console.

Steps taken:

```
Unzipped jboss-eap-6.4.zip
cd jboss-eap-6.4/bin 
sh add-user.sh
```

Created a Management User with a specific password and also an Application User with a specific password.

Started by local instance:

```
sh standalone.sh
```

Everything went perfectly well on server startup...

When I tried to access the management console and entered in the Managed User Name and Password pair, by going to this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
```

This is the JSON I received:

```
{"management-major-version" : 1, "management-micro-version" : 0, 
"management-minor-version" : 7, "name" : "mycomputer", "namespaces" : [], 
"product-name" : "EAP", "product-version" : "6.4.0.GA", "profile-name" : null, 
"release-codename" : "Janus", "release-version" : "7.5.0.Final-redhat-21", 
"schema-locations" : [], "core-service" : {"platform-mbean" : null,    
"management" : null, "service-container" : null, 
"server-environment" : null, "patching" : null, "module-loading" : null}, 
"deployment" : null, "deployment-overlay" : null, "extension" :
{"org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" : null, "org.jboss.as.connector" : null, 
"org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner" : null, "org.jboss.as.ee" : null,
"org.jboss.as.ejb3" : null, "org.jboss.as.jaxrs" : null, "org.jboss.as.jdr" : null, 
"org.jboss.as.jmx" : null, "org.jboss.as.jpa" : null,
"org.jboss.as.jsf" : null, "org.jboss.as.logging" : null,
"org.jboss.as.mail" : null, "org.jboss.as.naming" : null, 
"org.jboss.as.pojo" : null, "org.jboss.as.remoting" :   null,
"org.jboss.as.sar" : null, "org.jboss.as.security" : null,
"org.jboss.as.threads" : null, "org.jboss.as.transactions" : null,
"org.jboss.as.web" : null, "org.jboss.as.webservices" : null,
"org.jboss.as.weld" : null}, "interface" : {"management" : null,   
"public" : null, "unsecure" : null}, "path" : 
{"jboss.server.log.dir" : null, "jboss.server.data.dir" : null,
 "jboss.server.base.dir" : null, "jboss.server.config.dir" : null,
 "user.dir" : null, "user.home" : null, "jboss.server.temp.dir" 
 null, "jboss.controller.temp.dir" : null, "jboss.home.dir" : null,
 "java.home" : null}, "socket-binding-group" : {"standard-sockets" :
 null}, "subsystem" : {"jaxrs" : null, "jpa" : null, "ee" : null,
 "transactions" : null, "remoting" : null, "web" : null, "jmx" :
 null, "security" : null, "weld" : null, "pojo" : null, "infinispan" : null, 
"jca" : null, "datasources" : null, "logging" : null, "naming" : null, 
"webservices" : null, "jsf" : null, "jdr" : null, "deployment-scanner" : null, 
"ejb3" : null, "mail" : null, "threads" : null, "sar" : null,
"resource-adapters" : null}, "system-property" : null}
```

Is this supposed to be correct response?

Is the management console supposed to be accessed by going to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9990/
```

Would really appreciate if someone could clarify on this?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks to be expected behavior as you are hitting the [REST API management endpoint](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+HTTP+management+API).  You want to hit the [JBoss Management Console](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-The_Management_Console.html#Management_Console).  Try:

```
http://localhost:9990/console/App.html
```